# Request tracing through multiple azure networking components?

Tags: azure, networking

I have a solution in Azure that has multiple networking components, and am trying to trace requests through from component to component. I have enabled a LogAnalyticWorkspace that these components output to.

Application Gateway w/ WAFv2,
API Management Instance,
Application Gateway w/o WAF,
Container Instance,

AppGW-WAF-->APIM-->AppGW-->Container

Is there some common attribute/header value/query string addition, etc. that I can use in the LAW to trace a request from point to point in the sequence above?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you want to do tracing on the application / HTTP layer to get something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map?tabs=net#understanding-cloud-role-name-within-the-context-of-the-application-map)?!
[image]

Then you want to look at Application Insights and [Correlation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation), probably using [distributed tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/distributed-tracing).

This also nicely integrates out of the box with [APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights).